# AWS DMS "Load complete, replication ongoing" not working MongoDB to DocDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, replication, dms, aws-documentdb

I am trying to make a PoC for MongoDB to DocDB migration with DMS.
I've set up a MongoDB instance with some dummy data and an empty DocDB. Source and Target endpoints are also set in DMS and both of them are connecting successfully to my databases.

When I create a migration task in DMS everything seems to be working fine. All existing data is successfully replicated from the MongoDB instance to DocDB and the migration task state is at "**Load complete, replication ongoing**".
At this point I tried creating new entries in existing collections as well as creating new empty collections in MongoDB but nothing happens in DocDB. If I understand correctly the replication should be real time and anything I create should be replicated instantly?
Also there are no indication of errors or warnings whatsoever... I don't suppose its a connectivity issue to the databases since the initial data is being replicated.
Also the users I am using for the migration have admin privileges in both databases.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

@PPetkov - could you check the following?
1. Check if right privileges were assigned to the user in the MongoDB endpoint according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MongoDB.html.
2. Check if replicate set to capture changes was appropriately configured in the MongoDB instance. 
3. Once done, try to search for "]E:" or "]W:" in the CloudWatch logs to understand if there are any noticeable failures/warnings.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was using a local mongo exposed with tcp ngrok as a source database. Seems like that was the problem since a connection to our Stage mongo replica set worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue. For me, the problem was that, when I enabled change streams on the source DB (as per the AWS docs), I didn't change the `db_name` variable in the snippet provided:

```
db.adminCommand({modifyChangeStreams: 1,
   database: "db_name",
   collection: "", 
   enable: true});
```